# Making an image public in private repository

Tags: docker, docker-registry

We have a self hosted docker repository and want the ability to let our users on the network pull images in the repo without logging in. To push an image we still need them to login. Pull should be open though.

Like how docker hub works. You need to login to publish an image but anyone can pull it if it's marked public. Is there a way to make the image "public"?

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is not supported yet. From [docs](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/repos/):

> Note: You need to be signed in and have access to work with a private
>   repository.

What you can do is have them sign in and manage each user permission (to only pull or to be able to push and pull)